# MDX calculation for multiple measures

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube, dimension

I have to create the next calculation for 20 different Measures in my OLAP. As you can see the described function calculates the value of a measure the previous year. I have to repeat the code 20 times only changing the specific measure (`[Measures].[Sales]`) and I think there is a way of changing the specific measure dynamically.

```
create MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Sales ant] as
(ParallelPeriod(
             [Dim Calendar].[Calendar].[Year]
            ,1
            ,[Dim Calendar].[Calendar].CurrentMember
            ), [Measures].[Sales]),
 VISIBLE = 1  ,ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'Fact Sales';
```

Is there is a way in MDX to know which measure in the `[Measures]` group is being used? In this case which is the best way to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly you can create hidden set of measures like this:

```
CREATE HIDDEN STATIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[My Set Of Measures] AS 
{
[Measures].[Measure 1],
[Measures].[Measure 2],
[Measures].[Measure 3]
};
```

Then you can create scope assignment for this set:

```
Scope ([My Set Of Measures]);
this = (ParallelPeriod(
             [Dim Calendar].[Calendar].[Year]
            ,1
            ,[Dim Calendar].[Calendar].CurrentMember
            ), Measures.CurrentMember)
End Scope;
```

Note that instead of concrete measure - [Measures].[Sales] you will reference a measure with Measures.CurrentMember, so when you choose [Measures].[Sales] on your report the scope above will apply.

Hope it will work.